# Accessing MQTT node red outside the local network

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, node-red

I want to send some data from a SIM808 to a MQTT broker, which is node red installed on my raspberry pi 4. How can I get the node red to recieve and send MQTT outside the local network? I've seen a lot of tutorials but they are about purchasing a third party server host, which I dont want to do. I've already achieved MQTT with an esp32 over my local network, but I have no idea for doing that outside local network. Also I want to mention that it was suggested that for doing so, I needed to have a vpn. I decided to install WireGuard, and for some reason it just blocked all the raspberry pi internet traffic. Another question is that in my router I have this options for the port forwarding, but how do I use them? My raspberry pi is at 192.168.0.18 and the nodered port is at 1883, so if can anyone help me with that. Thanks[image]

Comment: Assuming you have a static IP address for your home broadband how to setup port forwarding is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) not Stack Overflow. If you do not have a Static IP address then you will also need to setup Dynamic DNS (again a question for SuperUser). If you are behind CGNAT then thinks get even harder.

Comment: Also DO NOT enable port forwarding to access the Node-RED editor before you have enabled AdminAuth (you will get hacked) https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#usernamepassword-based-authentication

Answer (score 0):

These videos show how to set remote access to your RPi and a node-red server running on it, using cloudflare tunnels (which are free to use, just sign-up to cloudflare).
With this method, you don't need to deploy a VPN as the traffic will be proxied by cloudflare.
Just make sure you set the ingress rules correctly,

- for node-red tcp port (1880), and
- mqtt broker tcp port (1883).

Watch these videos with step-by-step guides: https://youtu.be/Z6b3l1z0N7w and this: https://youtu.be/cInnpVEW50k